# ROC/AUC Curve for False Negatives (Type 2 Errors)?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, auc, precision

I keep seeing this curve and I understand this basically tells you how well the model is doing in terms of predicting True positives vs. False positives.

[image]

I was wondering if there is a version of this curve that plots True negatives vs. False negatives, or combines it with the previous True positives vs. False positives plot in any way? Because right now it only shows you how well the model does with respect to False Positives, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since there are just two categories, and the TNR and FNR are so related to the TPR and FPR, this sounds like a graph that would not contain new information. Let's see what happens in a simulation.

```r
library(pROC)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(2023)
N <- 1000 
p <- rbeta(N, 1, 1) # Pick some event probabilities
y <- rbinom(N, 1, p) # Simulate events with those probabilities
r <- pROC::roc(y, p)
plot(r)
points(1 - r$specificities, 1 - r$sensitivities)
d0 <- data.frame(
  x = 1 - r$specificities,
  y = r$sensitivities,
  Curve = "Normal ROC"
)
d1 <- data.frame(
  x = 1 - (1 - r$specificities), # so just specificity
  y = 1 - r$sensitivities,
  Curve = "Negatives"
)
d <- rbind(d0, d1)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, col = Curve)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_abline(slope = 1, intercept = 0)
```

[image: Both curves]

Perhaps you get something out of the pink plot that you do not get out of the usual ROC curve in blue. If you do (I do not), the formula for plotting the pink curve is straightforward and has as straightforward of an interpretation as the usual ROC curve (maybe explain to clients that you want such curve to tend toward the lower right instead of the upper left as evidence of good separation between the two groups).

The pink plot about negative predictions (as opposed to the usual ROC curve that deals with positive predictions) might be a useful visualization for a particular project. However, we are not majorly losing out on information by considering the usual ROC curve that deals with positive predictions. Each plot is just a mirror-image of the other, reflected about the line $y=x$.

Comment: Visualization always get the point across

Comment: If you want to reverse the $x$ and $y$ axes, that is straightforward to implement in the code. I still see no information conveyed but such a plot that is not conveyed by the usual ROC curve, but it might be a useful visualization for a project that is focused on the negative cases. However, I stand by my claim that we are not majorly losing out on information in the plot by focusing on positives in the ROC curve. In the binary case, positives and negatives are two sides of the same coin. (If we know the coin landed on heads, we know it did not land on tails.)

Comment: I think some information may have been lost in translation. What I intended to say is that your visualization effectively conveyed why there is no new information in a way that was easy to understand.

Comment: @Firebug Pardon me if that came across as criticism. I was typing the comment when yours appeared, and it is not in response to you. // In response to you, thanks! I wasn't totally sure what would happen in the visualization and if it would convey information in a particularly useful way.

Comment: I see, so just to check my understanding, you're saying a good model with a high true positive+low false positive rate always indicates it also has a high true negative+low false negative rate? And thank you for displaying this in a graphical form so that it is much easier to understand.

Comment: @Katsu I think that’s right, but I am a bit too goofy after the time change to be comfortable trying to give an explanation (I tried and confused myself). Perhaps I will have my brain back tomorrow and can post a better comment or edit in some additional explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 7):

The ROC curve is the curve
$$f(t) = (\mathrm{FPR}(t), \mathrm{TPR}(t)),$$

for a threshold $t \in \mathbb R$.

You are proposing a new curve $g(t) = (\mathrm{FNR}(t), \mathrm{TNR}(t))$, but remember that $\mathrm{TPR} = 1 - \mathrm{FNR}$ and $\mathrm{FPR} = 1 - \mathrm{TNR}$, so that:
$$g(t) = (1-\mathrm{TPR}(t), 1-\mathrm{FPR}(t))$$
is simply a mirrored version of $f(t)$.

Comment: (+1) I didn’t think of the mirrored insight.

Comment: By the way, shouldn’t $f(t) = (\mathrm{FPR}(t), \mathrm{TPR}(t))$ since FPR in OP’s diagram is plotted along the x-axis? It doesn’t really matter, but I thought to mention it.

Comment: @mhdadk Good point, thanks! I believe people are more used to that convention

Comment: Sorry I just edited your answer by accident. Will roll back.